# Copy background color from one cell to cell in separate sheet using ms-excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to copy background color for example sheetA cell A1 to
sheet B A1.

The cell A1 is using conditional formatting, I can copy simple but not with conditional formatting enabled.

Here is the code

```
Dim varTemp As Variant

varTemp = Worksheets("Summary").Range("F15:F21").Formula
Worksheets("People").Range("G3:G9").Copy
Worksheets("Summary").Range("F15:F21").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
Worksheets("Summary").Range("F15:F21").Formula = varTemp
```

when I run the VB it just select the target cells and ask me to PASTE the results. So the bottom left status bar in [image: video]

Comment: Is the background color conditionally formatted?

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me, it copies the cell (background) colors into other cells in a different sheet.

```
Sub copyFormat()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("a1:b1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("a1:b1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
End Sub
```